# ImportError: cannot import name 'test' from 'lib'

Tags: python-3.x, import, package

as you can see in the picture down below, I created a TEST package, with two sub-packages(test1, test2), this is the structure of the package:

```
\test
   | __pycache__.py # ki importit lib fell main tcrea
   | __init__.py
   | lib.py
   | \test1
   |     | __init__.py
   |     | test1.py
   | \test2
   |     | __init__.py
   |     | test2.py
```

I wanted to import lib inside test1.py
I have tried the next code( as I sawed in the tutorials):

```py
import lib
lib.test()

# from lib import test
# test()

# from ..lib import test
# test()
```

I tried to execute the code with vs code cmd from the TEST package then I entered to test1 sub-package(cd .\test1) to try but it didn't work.
I got those errors:
[image]

THANKS FOR HELP!!

Comment: According to your screenshot, you created `test` package, not `TEST` package. You also do not seem to have the `lib` module anywhere.

Comment: yeah, a test package thanks, i created lib inside test package

Comment: Have you tried `from test import lib`?

Comment: yes i did, it gives me this error==> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dud'